# JavaFX tableView play button for a music player?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a working TableView in a javaFX musicPlayer application with the columns: Name, Artist, Album, Duration. How would I make it so that no matter which column I press, my application plays whatever song is selected when I double click? I have a Song class with a Play() method F.Y.I.

Thanks

Comment: Include a minimal example of related code that shows what you have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom [`TableRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.html) factory:

```
TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
    tableView.setRowFactory(cb -> {
        TableRow<String> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> {
            if(ev.getClickCount() > 1) {

            }
        });
        return row;
    });
```

Hint: You can access the rows item with `TableRow.getItem()`.